# TextView inside ScrollView clips text off

Tags: android, bufferedreader

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/privacyPolicyTitle"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/privacy_policy" />

   <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="9">
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/privacyPolicyText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my XML layout. The text that comes into `TextView` in the `ScrollView` comes from a `BufferedReader` that reads it from the assets. However, the text is not displayed from the first line, it is displayed from the second paragraph. Why is it so?

Comment: Before setting just check whether all the data you want to put on the TextView is there in the specified variable. Just put a log or system.out.print. If the data is there, then we might have a problem and need to dig deeper on why such a thing is happening.

Comment: @autocrat I set a `marginTop` of `500dp` and now it doesnt clip off :-/ That shows that the data is there

Comment: 500dp :O WOW! So any insights to what the problem might have been?

Comment: @autocrat Not a clue!